# Row conditional column operations in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large data.table where I for each row need to make computations based on part of the full data.table. As an example consider the following data.table, and assume I for each row want to compute the sum of the num variable for every rows where id2 matches id1 for the current row as well as the time variable is within distance 1 from the time of the current row.

```
set.seed(123)

dat <- data.table(cbind(id1=sample(1:5,10,replace=T),
                        id2=sample(1:5,10,replace=T),
                        num=sample(1:10,10,replace=T),
                        time=sample(1:10,10,replace=T)))
```

This could easily be done by looping over each row like this

```
dat[,val:= 0]
for (i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  this.val <- dat[ (id2==id1[i]) & (time>=time[i]-2) & (time<=time[i]+2),sum(num)]
  dat[i,val:=this.val]
}

dat
```

The resulting data.table looks like this:

```
   > dat
        id1 id2 num time val
     1:   2   5   9   10   6
     2:   4   3   7   10   0
     3:   3   4   7    7  10
     4:   5   3  10    8   9
     5:   5   1   7    1   2
     6:   1   5   8    5   6
     7:   3   2   6    8  17
     8:   5   1   6    3  10
     9:   3   2   3    4   0
    10:   3   5   2    3   0
```

What is the proper/fast way to do things like this using data.table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use a self-join here by creating the 'timeminus2' and 'timeplus2' column, join `on` by 'id2' with 'id1' and the non-equi logical condition to get the `sum` of 'num' and assign (`:=`) the 'val' column to the original dataset

```
tmp <- dat[.(id1 = id1, timeminus2 = time - 2, timeplus2 = time + 2), 
             .(val = sum(num)),
             on = .(id2 = id1, time >= timeminus2, time <= timeplus2),
             by = .EACHI
         ][is.na(val), val := 0][]
dat[, val := tmp$val][]
#     id1 id2 num time val
# 1:   2   5   9   10   6
# 2:   4   3   7   10   0
# 3:   3   4   7    7  10
# 4:   5   3  10    8   9
# 5:   5   1   7    1   2
# 6:   1   5   8    5   6
# 7:   3   2   6    8  17
# 8:   5   1   6    3  10
# 9:   3   2   3    4   0
#10:   3   5   2    3   0
```

Comment: Thanks, this made my code more than 100 times faster :-)
Just out of curiosity: Is it somehow possible to include other variables in tmp, such that one could avoid the need to write back to the original dataset?

Comment: @Mark Just like I created the `.(id1, ...)`, you can place those variables inside.